# Access Current Subject which can be reused using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attributes, cypress

I have few elements which appear on the page with a `data-testid` attribute.

[image]

The attribute has values which define what kind of element it is.
I want to use the attribute value as a string and want to push it into an array.

What I am doing is -

```
        cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL)
             .children(NODE_TYPE)
             .each((el) => {
                 orderArray.push(cy.get(el).invoke('attr', 'data-testid'));
             })
```

but it isn't adding anything to the array, but the assertions

`cy.get(el).invoke('attr', 'data-testid').should('eq', 'Single Column sm')`

are working fine.

Comment: Are you trying to push the innerText values for these elements to the array? Also, can you expand one of the div's and post a screenshot of the DOM.

Comment: The value of attribute into an array.
```Single Column sm``` for instance in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, to get the value of your desired attribute and save it in an array:

```
cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL)
  .children(NODE_TYPE)
  .each((el) => {
    cy.wrap(el).invoke('attr', 'data-testid').then((val) => {
      orderArray.push(val);
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Alapan. That worked! 
The ```wrap()``` and ```then()``` functions are the key ! thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The `.children()` command returns a set of elements, so instead of looping through them (which can fail under certain circumstances) you can **map the element to the attribute**.

Please see this blog [Iterate Over Elements](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/recipes/iterate.html#using-cy-invoke-and-each) for more comprehensive examples for the options

```js
cy.get(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL)
  .invoke('map', (k, el) => {
    return el.getAttribute('data-testid')
  })
  // convert jQuery object to an array
  .invoke('toArray')
  .then(orderArray => {
    // use the array
  })
```

or using `cy.map()`

```js
cy.get(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL)
  .map(el => el.getAttribute('data-testid'))
  .then(orderArray => {
    // use the array
  })
```